¿Cómo puedo sumar los números dado un rango usando los blucles for y while en Python?
Tengo un problema en donde necesito sumar valores dados en un rango. El rango va desde 524 hasta 10508, y esos valores deben estar incluidos en la suma. Además, quiero usar los bucles while y for.
    for i in range(524,10508):
        i=0;
        while i < 10508 and i > 524:
            print (sum(i))
            i=i+1

Este es el código que hice, pero al momento de ejecutarlo, no me da ninguna respuesta.

No se justifica el while, ya que estas controlando los valores en el range( inicio, fin ). Y para acumar la suma, solo necesitas una variable donde ir almacenando tus sum(i)

No hace nada porque tu segundo ciclo, el while, nunca itera:
i=0;
while i < 10508 and i > 524:

asignas a i el valor de 0 justo antes de iniciar el ciclo y la condición del while es que itere mientras i sea menor de 10508 y mayor de 524, 0 es menor que 524, luego el while no itera ni una sola vez.
Si iterara, sum(i) te generaría un TypeError porque sum() necesita un iterable como primer argumento e i es un entero, un solo número, no una serie de numero a sumar...
Si lo que quieres es simplemente sumar todos los números del intervalo, usar ambos ciclos no tiene sentido, el for range ya te genera el rango de números e itera sobre ellos asignándoselos a i, el while no sirve absolutamente para nada:
suma = 0
for i in range(524, 10509):  # 10508 + 1 si quieres que se incluya en la suma
    suma += i
print(suma)

o con un while puedes hacer algo como:
suma = 0
i = 524
while i <= 10508:
    suma += i
    i += 1
print(suma)

o usando el operador morsa:
i = suma = 524
while (i := i + 1) <= 10508:
    suma += i
print(suma)

Aunque si quieres usar sum() no necesitas ningún ciclo, acepta un iterable y range es un iterable totalmente válido:
print(sum(range(524, 10509)))

En todos los casos 524 y 10508 se incluyen en la suma. sum(range()) es el más simple y el más eficiente, seguido del for in range() y por último el while, que es el menos eficiente y el menos apropiado para esta tarea (los ciclos while son especialmente útiles por ejemplo cuando no conocemos a priori el numero máximo de iteraciones, que no es el caso).

Realmente hay una forma mucho más eficiente que requiere iterar 0 veces:
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋯ (Suma infinita cuyos términos son los números naturales - Wikipedia)
Que en su aplicación más cruda, sin simplificar nada seria:
print(10508 * (10508 + 1) // 2 - 524 * (524 - 1) // 2)

